# Test twitters php api locally without ssl

Tags: php, curl, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to get twitter to post to my wall via php and the only way I can see to do it is by first having a auth tocken and to get that I need to ask twitter for it :) Facebook do it better ;p

So I am using [ricardoper/twitteroauth](https://github.com/ricardoper) to do this and when trying to get the tockens I get this back from hitting the curl file seen here: https://github.com/ricardoper/TwitterOAuth/blob/v2/src/Common/Curl.php

I am unsure if its because I'm running php locally or if its something to do with twitter.

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught cURL Lib: [60] SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (TwitterOAuth\Exception\CurlException) 
  thrown in <b>C:\var\www\fbshare\TwitterOAuth\src\Common\Curl.php</b> on line <b>110</b><br />
```

How can i overcome this error, or be able to post to twitter, but I believe this script does that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the repo I was using's `pem` wasn't supporting ssl on the local host.

I download a local `ssl` certificate from [here](https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download)

Replaced line 64 with `CURLOPT_CAINFO => '/var/www/cacert.pem',` which was the downloaded `pem` from the link given above and now I can access ssl locally :)